# Applying *args and indicating string values in merging columns function

Tags: python, function, apache-spark, pyspark, args

I am using the following function, but want to apply `args` (instead of `column1`, `column2`) to make the amount of columns variable. Also I want to give in the arguments that the args should be string values.

Does anybody know how to implement this?

```
def create_new_column_by_merging_columns(spark_df, new_column, column_1, column_2):
    spark_df_with_new_column = spark_df.withColumn(new_column, sf.concat(sf.col(column_1), sf.lit('_'), sf.col(column_2)))
    
    return spark_df_with_new_column


new_df_with_merged_columns = create_new_column_by_merging_columns(spark_df, new_column, column_1, column_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`concat_ws`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html) function which does exactly what you're looking for:

> `pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws(sep, *cols)`
>
> Concatenates multiple input string columns together into a single
> string column, using the given separator.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn(new_column, F.concat_ws("_", column1, column2, ...))
```

However, if you really need to have a function, then you can define it as below:

```
def merge_columns(df, new_column, *cols):
    return df.withColumn(new_column, F.concat_ws("_", *cols))
```